# orientation of three points in a plane

Tags: geometry

we are given three points $p_1(x_1,y_1)$, $p_2(x_2,y_2)$ and $p_3(x_3,y_3)$
and I have to determine whether they are collinear ,clockwise or counterclockwise.

This the expression that I got after searching the web but I can't find a logical way to prove it .Till now I have observed that the expression is the numerator obtained by subtracting the slopes of $p_1 p_2$ and $p_2 p_3$.

(y2 - y1)*(x3 - x2) - (y3 - y2)*(x2 - x1)

Above expression is negative , i.e., counterclockwise

Above expression is 0  i.e., collinear

Above expression is positive  i.e., clockwise

Comment: What are $\sigma$ and $\tau$? And how do you deal with the cases where two of the points have the same $x$ coordinate?

Comment: How are the functions $p_i(x,y)$ defined?

Comment: Try relating these expressions to the interpretation of a determinant as a signed area.

Comment: edited the question a little.

Comment: The triangle Area  has a sign when considering its  $(3X3)$ matrix It can be better put to similar use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View the coordinates of the points as the coordinate representation of the vectors that point from the origin to the points and extend the underlying space from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ by adding a third coordinate component $0$.

Now, $P_1,P_2,P_3$ becomes $(x_1,y_1,0), (x_2,y_2,0), (x_3,y_3,0)$ , respectively. Considering all 6 possible configurations of the three points, one will find that

1. $d=0\Leftrightarrow$ the triangle spanned by the two vectors has no area $\to$ the three points are collinear.
2. $d>0$ so the cross product points in the positive $z$ direction, meaning
   the three points are counter-clockwise.
3. $d<0: the cross product points in the negative $z$ direction i.e., the three points are clockwise

where $\overrightarrow{P_1P_2}\times\overrightarrow{P_1P_3} = (0,0,d)$.
Also,
$\overrightarrow{P_1P_2}\times\overrightarrow{P_1P_3}
= (x_2-x_1, y_2-y_1, 0)\times(x_3-x_1, y_3-y_1, 0)
= (0,0,(x_2-x_1)(y_3-y_1)-(x_3-x_1)(y_2-y_1))
d = (x_2-x_1)(y_3-y_1)-(x_3-x_1)(y_2-y_1)$

Comment: Sorry can't see your full answer due to maths processing error.

Comment: You can do the same thing without ever leaving $\mathbb R^2$ by using determinants instead of cross products.

Answer (score 0):

An answer without vector arithmetic.

Translate $p_1, p_2$, and $p_3$ so that $p_2$ is at (0,0). Rotate the points about p2 until p3 is on the positive x axis. Neither action changes the relevant relationship among the points.

With $x_2$ = $y_2$ = $y_3$ = 0, the expression simplifies to -$y_1$$x_3$

$x_3$ $\neq$ 0, else $p_3$ = (0, 0) = $p_2$

So if -$y_1$$x_3$ = 0, $y_1$ = 0, meaning $p_1$ is on the x-axis and the 3 points are colinear.

$p_3$ is on the positive x-axis so $x_3$ is positive

If -$y_1$$x_3$ > 0, -$y_1$ > 0, so $y_1$ < 0, putting $p_1$ in quadrant III or IV, and the $p_1p_2p_3$ is clockwise.

If -$y_1$$x_3$ < 0, -$y_1$ < 0, so $y_1$ > 0, putting $p_1$ in quadrant I or II, and the $p_1p_2p_3$ is counter clockwise.